# HockeyApp missing in Visual Studio 19

Tags: visual-studio

I recently upgraded from Visual Studio 2017 to 2019.

When I tried to distribute my app, I right-clicked on the project and looked for the HockeyApp menu, but it is no longer present.

Has Microsoft moved or renamed this functionality? If so, where do I find it now?

Comment: Is `HockeyApp` a solution that you developed?

Comment: I think MS is calling it App Center now.